# What's a way for sleeping without spinning in javascript running from a data URI?

Tags: javascript, flash, sleep, chromium, data-uri

I need a way to sleep in javascript. Yes, I know about `setTimeout` and so on, but those won't do for me. I need a real sleep. One that freezes the tab or the browser. But preferably without spinning the CPU. Yes, I really, really need that. I'm sure, and I really know what I'm doing.

Of course, from a webpage that was loaded over HTTP, I could just do a synchronous GET request to `/cgi-bin/sleep.sh?5000` or so (precision doesn't matter for me). However, I'm in a data URI context, so I need something more generic. I could embed a java applet and call its Thread.sleep from Javascript, I think, but I don't want to require Java. And flash doesn't seem to be able to do blocking HTTP requests.

So, does anyone know a way to sleep in a data uri context just using javascript and flash? Chromium-specific answers are ok.

<sub>I guess my reputation will go down after asking this...</sub>

Comment: +1 for `Yes, I really, really need that. I'm sure, and I really know what I'm doing.`

Comment: Could you explain why you really, really need sleep. I'm curious about the kind of case that would need sleep() and where setTimeout() wouldn't do it.

Comment: @Aralicia It's for a PoC for a security issue. I need to preserve the upper stack frames for some time. Spinning the CPU can do it, but that doesn't look so nice.

Comment: Well, I now found out that actually, in my case, synchronous GET requests would do the job, but still, that's not sooo nice for PoC code, so I'll leave this open.

Answer (score 0):

You need to to do that with `setTimeout` and a callback. There's no `sleep` in JavaScript. 
Definitively no. 
Period.